# How do I stop my system randomly suspending?

Tags: suspend, power-management

I've got an Ubuntu machine running as a plex server and after a lot of work I've managed to get it to auto/wake suspend using a bash script and crontab that I found on here.

It should turn on at 10:30am and off at 2:00am.

It's turning on and off okay (if I wake it up) however something is causing my system to suspend around 5-7pm, and I was wondering is there a log file or something I can check to see what's causing it?

Found what's putting my system to sleep:

```
Aug 02 18:44:36 <Computer Name> NetworkManager[688]: <info>  [1470159876.6691] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Aug 02 18:44:36 <Computer Name> NetworkManager[688]: <info>  [1470159876.6692] manager: sleeping...
Aug 02 18:44:37 <Computer Name> systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 02 18:44:37 <Computer Name> systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
```

Does anyone know what's happening here and what I should do to stop it?!

Comment: `journalctl` might tell you what suspends your system.

Comment: Thanks for that: Identified the problem - now just need to solve the next part!

Comment: @Rekhyt Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm having the same issue. Thanks.